# Search and retrieving word(s) from multiple tables from SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

User is passing searching keywords to one or more databases and finding each word in multiple tables and count number of rows where word is found.

So What I did is here.. I was looping in each word from word array and password this word to each table and retrieving row count. Now I am getting a time out error here while searching multiple keywords and 590 in tables. because for looping keywords and calling tables multiple times. See my code.

**VB.NET code**

```
 For Each keyword As String In keywords
    For Each lstOfSelectedTable As String In lstOfSelectedTables
        Dim words As List(Of String) = lstOfSelectedTable.Split("."c).ToList()
            If words.Count > 1 Then
               dbName = words(0)
               schema = words(1)
               tableName = words(2)
               If strKeywords.Length > 0 Then
                  dtExcel = FillData(keyword, schema, tableName, serverName, dbName)
                  If dtExcel.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                     If CType(dtExcel.Rows(0).Item(3), Integer) > 0 Then
                        ds.Tables.Add(dtExcel)
                     End If
                  End If

               End If
        End If
 Next
```

Next

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FindStringInTable] @stringToFind VARCHAR(100), @schema sysname, @table sysname, @dbname varchar(100)
AS 


DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(Max) 
DECLARE @where NVARCHAR(Max)
DECLARE @columnName sysname 
DECLARE @cursor VARCHAR(8000) 


BEGIN TRY 
   SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT '''+ @stringToFind +''' as ''Keyword'','''+@dbname +''' As ''Database'', '''+ @table +''' as ''Table'',count(*) as Count FROM [' + @dbname + '].[' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] WHERE' 
   SET @where = '' 


   SET @cursor = 'DECLARE col_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
   FROM ' + @dbname + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @schema + ''' 
   AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @table + ''' 
   AND DATA_TYPE IN (''char'',''nchar'',''ntext'',''nvarchar'',''text'',''varchar'')' 


  PRINT @cursor
   EXEC (@cursor) 

   OPEN col_cursor    
   FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO @columnName    

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
   BEGIN    
       IF @where <> '' 
           SET @where = @where + ' OR'

       SET @where = @where + ' [' + @columnName + '] LIKE ''%' + @stringToFind + '%''' 
       FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO @columnName 
       PRINT @columnName   
   END    


   CLOSE col_cursor    
   DEALLOCATE col_cursor  


   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @where 
   PRINT @sqlCommand 
    IF @where <> '' 
        EXEC (@sqlCommand)  
    ELSE
        RETURN 

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
 SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
   PRINT 'There was an error. Check to make sure object exists.' 
   IF CURSOR_STATUS('variable', 'col_cursor') <> -3 
   BEGIN 
       CLOSE col_cursor    
       DEALLOCATE col_cursor  
   END 
END CATCH
```

I am passing like this.

```
 exec sp_FindStringInTable 'Application','dbo','BAK_tbl_Timeline_032112','Sui_WIP'  
 exec sp_FindStringInTable 'Application','dbo','tbl_SampleList','Sui_WIP' 
 exec sp_FindStringInTable 'Insurance','dbo','BAK_tbl_Timeline_032112','Sui_WIP'  
 exec sp_FindStringInTable 'Insurance','dbo','tbl_SampleList','Sui_WIP' 
 exec sp_FindStringInTable 'Reduced','dbo','BAK_tbl_Timeline_032112','Sui_WIP'  
 exec sp_FindStringInTable 'Reduced','dbo','tbl_SampleList','Sui_WIP'
```

Continually for around 600 tables. Now I want optimize store procedure.

```
exec sp_FindStringInTable 'Application;Insurance;Reduced','dbo','BAK_tbl_Timeline_032112','Sui_WIP'
exec sp_FindStringInTable 'Application;Insurance;Reduced','Person','Person','AdventureWorks'
```

Please help me out changing this sp and run efficiently.

**NOTE: User can pass multilple words by selecting multiple DBs (or) All Databases in the server and Selecting multiple Tables (or) All Tables on databases.**

Comment: And you want that specification (*User can pass multilple words by selecting multiple DBs (or) All Databases in the server and Selecting multiple Tables (or) All Tables on databases*) to run efficiently?, that's not gonna be easy

Comment: Lamak: at least we can check by passing one by database and users selection table or all tables also fine.

Comment: I don't agree you are getting a timeout because of looping.  The timeout is based on a single call.   Increase the timeout.  LIKE ''%' kills use of any index.   Have you considered add Full Text on the databases and index those columns?

Comment: Blam, I did not looked at Full Text yet, I am web developer and not deeply on DB. For index, It is not in my hand, because user can select any db or multiple DBs. There may be bunch tables to search keyword. Is there anything wrong in the SP or VB.net code?

Comment: I added a plus vote to @Blam comment because his suggestion is really more of an answer and it is THE answer if you want the best performance out of what you're trying to do. If you created a full text index on all the columns and tables you wanted to query you could accomplish what you're trying to do in a couple line select statement looped across all the tables you added to the fulltext index. Configuring a fulltextindex is easy through SSMS and for information on how to query it search for "CONTAINSTABLE". While you would still need a cursor you wouldn't need dynamic SQL and it's fast!

Comment: OOps.. My server for full-text search feature not installed or not configured.

Comment: Like "% kills any index.   All table scans.  BIG hit.   Then install and configure Full Text.

Answer (score 1):

This query searches for the substring to all db, which have tables with text fields. Try the script, it may be helpful.

```
DECLARE @phrase NVARCHAR(100)
SELECT @phrase = 'str'

DECLARE 
      @db_name SYSNAME
    , @output NVARCHAR(200)

DECLARE db CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT d.name
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.state_desc = 'ONLINE'
        AND d.name NOT IN ('tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'master')
    ORDER BY d.name

OPEN db

FETCH NEXT FROM db INTO @db_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT @output = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), GETDATE(), 114) + ': Find in ' + QUOTENAME(@db_name) + ':'
    RAISERROR(@output, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT

    DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    USE [' + @db_name + ']; 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql = ''USE [' + @db_name + '];'' + (
        SELECT 
            CHAR(13) + 
                ''IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM '' + 
                QUOTENAME(s.name) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + 
                '' WHERE'' + b.cols + '') PRINT ''''['' + 
                s.name + ''].['' + o.name + '']'''';'' 
        FROM sys.objects o
        JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
        JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT p.[object_id] 
            FROM sys.partitions p
            WHERE p.[rows] > 0
        ) p ON p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT cols = STUFF((
                SELECT ''OR CHARINDEX(''''' + @phrase + ''''', '' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + '') > 0 '' 
                FROM sys.columns c
                JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
                WHERE t.name IN (''char'', ''nchar'', ''ntext'', ''nvarchar'', ''text'', ''varchar'')
                    AND c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
                ORDER BY c.column_id
                FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE, ROOT).value(''root[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, '''')
        ) b
        WHERE o.[type] = ''U''
            AND b.cols IS NOT NULL
        FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE, ROOT).value(''root[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
    '

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @tsql
    PRINT REPLICATE('-', 100) + CHAR(13)

    FETCH NEXT FROM db INTO @db_name

END

CLOSE db
DEALLOCATE db
```

Or try this -

```
DECLARE @char NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @char = 'str'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = (
    SELECT CHAR(13) + 
        'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ' + 
            QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + 
            ' WHERE' + b.cols + ')  
        SELECT table_name = ''[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'' ' + c.cols +' FROM ' + 
            QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + 
            ' WHERE' + b.cols + ';' 
    FROM sys.objects o
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT p.[object_id] 
        FROM sys.partitions p
        WHERE p.[rows] > 0
    ) p ON p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT cols = STUFF((
            SELECT 'OR CHARINDEX(''' + @char + ''', ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') > 0 ' 
            FROM sys.columns c
            JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
            WHERE t.name IN ('char', 'nchar', 'ntext', 'nvarchar', 'text', 'varchar')
                AND c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
    ) b
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT cols = (
            SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' ' 
            FROM sys.columns c
            JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
            WHERE t.name IN ('char', 'nchar', 'ntext', 'nvarchar', 'text', 'varchar')
                AND c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ) c
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
        AND b.cols IS NOT NULL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```